# Support Vector Machine Primal Form Implementation

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, svm

I am currently working on a support vector machine (SVM) project. The version of SVM that I am working on is [Linear SVM in Primal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Primal_form) and I am having hard time understanding where to start.

In general, I think I understand the theory; basically I need to minimize norm of w under certain constraint. And the Lagrangian function will be my objective function to be minimized (after Lagrange multiplier is applied).

The things that I don't understand is that I was told from my professor that we will be using Quasi-Newton method along with BFGS update. I have tried 2D and 3D case for Newton's method and I think I have good grasp of the algorithm, but I don't see how Quasi-Newton method is applied to find the coefficients alpha. Also, many literature that I read so far tells to apply Quadratic programming to find the coefficients.

How is the iterative algorithm of Quasi-Newton related to finding coefficients of w...? And how is quadratic programming related to Quasi-Newton? Can anyone please walk me through what is going on?

Comment: This question is too broad for any Stack Exchange site, and the topic is better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/. Read through the help center there and write a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cunfusing many things here

- "alpha coefficients" are **only in the dual form**, so you **do not find them** in your case
- "apply Quadratic programming", quadratic programming is a **problem**, not a solution. you cannot "apply QP", you can only **solve** a QP, which in your case will be solved using quasi-newton method
- "how is (...) related to finding coefficientss of w" exactly the same way, as this optimization technique is related to finding the optimal coefficients of any function. You are going to minimize the function **of w**, so applying any optimization technique (in particular quasi-netwton) will lead to solution expressed as **w** coefficients

Comment: Okay, so then I will be solving a QP problem now I understand. I have another question. As far as I understand the QP problem is second and thrid term of a Taylor expansion my objective function (is this right? or the f(x) that QP refer to is something different?). But why minimize those? And by doing so, why exactly am I getting out of it? Do I get next index like how Newton's method works? I know I have a lot of question, but please help me here..

Comment: If you have another question, you should ask a separate one, comments are not the place for such discussions. QP problem is simply the problem of minimizing/maximizing the quadratic function with linear constraints. That's all. It has nothing to do with Taylos expansions of any function.

Comment: So is it coincident that when you apply the Taylor expansion of a function the second and third term is exactly the same as what QP
is minimizing?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method

Comment: And BTW thanks for your input. I really appreciated. This is my first time asking question at Stackoverflow.. so please bare with me if I am not following by the rule. I will next time for sure..

Comment: No, it is not a coincidence, but this is the other way around. if you want to optimize the Taylor expension to third term you arrive at a particular case of unconstrained quadratic optimization problem. But this does not apply in the other way, QP's are not "taylor expansions" (although for each QP problem you can find a function which has a taylor expansion of such form).